# Asp.Net MVC Multiple Html.Actions On Same Page? What is the correct way to avoid this?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

Working on a site that has a structure of a main navigation that is defined in my shared "_Layout.cshtml" page and links on the main nav that will take you to different pages that have a separate navigation bar that is unique to that page.

[image]

(something like this^).

Currently I just have my second nav and main content all on the same page and have a ton of different tabs with Html.Actions rendered and they are toggled by clicking a link on the second navigation and changing the tab.  This works but it makes my initial page load extremely slow since I believe they are all being loaded at once.

**Html for tabs:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Action("tab1", new ViewDataDictionary { { "item", m.item }, { "item2", m.item2 } })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Action("tab2", new ViewDataDictionary { { "item", m.item }, { "item2", m.item2 } })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Action("tab3", new ViewDataDictionary { { "item", m.item }, { "item2", m.item2 } })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Action("tab4", new ViewDataDictionary { { "item", m.item }, { "item2", m.item2
        } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any alternative that would be better for a layout that has multiple secondary navigation bars that change depending on the link clicked on the "_Layout.cshtml" page?

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex pages that are getting loaded all in advance, and this is slow...alternatives would be:

1. Make the tabs just links to other pages that use the same tabs on them but aren't actually loaded.  This will look the same, but--naturally--navigating from one tab to the next will be slower since everything isn't pre-loaded.
2. Use javascript to dynamically load the content when the user clicks on the tab.  E.g. using [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  This has more complexity but fits better with your current setup.